# How to connect my app users with their facebook id's?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

In my app I need to find a way to connect users with their facebook ids (or something, that will identify them later). Will try to explain:

1. As a user,I'm create an event, and mark participants by enter their names.
2. Some of participants are already sign up in my app, some of them not.
3. To identify participant (no matter, registered or not),I have planned to use their facebook ids. Currently,I want add links to their profiles under names.

So, is there a way to get facebook id of user, by his profile link (https://facebook.com/zuck)? Or any other way to identify user via facebook, no matter registered he in app or not.

**UPDATE** Looks like there are no way to use facebook IDs for this task. Maybe there are another identifier to uniquely link account with facebook?

Comment: Something like [this](https://www.quora.com/Whats-the-easiest-way-to-get-a-persons-Facebook-user-ID-if-Im-looking-at-that-persons-profile) you need?

Comment: No, you can not get someone’s user id from their user name - not in any allowed way. And even if you did use some external service to get their global id - it would not help you much, because when they sign up for your app, you will only get an _app-scoped_ user id.

Comment: Thanks, i update question. Is there are any other way to link facebook with my internal account.